# SVG: change color on hover without using a <style> tag

Tags: svg

I need to export an SVG with some interaction on hover. In the specific change colors.

If I export the SVG and I use a `<style>` tag to add the hover animation and change color, this overrides other svgs on the page.

As my SVG is really complex, how can avoid this to happen and still have the hover animation?

```
 <svg>
    <style>
    #level_1:hover .st5 {fill: #BE82FA;}
    </style>
 </svg>
```

Comment: The [<load-file> Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) allows to load the SVG **_and_** styles inside shadowDOM, so styles do not leak in, or out.

Comment: You probably have more elements with the ID level_1. IDs must be unique. Either rename some of the IDs or use class names for the element and your CSS selectors.